# SSH - Wrong AllowUsers can't connect anymore

Tags: ssh, root

I appended `AllowUsers` with the wrong user to my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` then restarted the service. So I can't connect anymore.

Is there a way to recover without physical access ?

Comment: If you have no physical access to the server, then you can't do anything AFAIK.

Comment: Without physical access you have to hack your server

Comment: I'd like to know what's wrong with my question. Thx

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY: It's probably that it's off-topic on StackOverflow, and should have been posted on ServerFault instead.

Comment: Ok I see, I didn't even thought about it, would make sense indeed. It would not deserve -1 though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to log in locally at the machine in order to fix it, quite simply.

If you have no local access to it, then you're in more dire straights, and need to deliberate with whomever it is that hosts the machine. If it's a server hosting firm, they often offer the possibility to reboot machines into some kind of rescue system, but you'd need to check with the hosting firm itself, since there's no universal formula for such things.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Hopefully I've been able to contact a local guy. Thx